# Code igniter MVC ajax delete not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

why is this failing.
 my view code

```
function Dispose(id){

if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
    {
        // ajax delete data to database
            $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('Login/ajax_delete')?>" , 
            type: 'post',
            data: {'id' : id},
            success: function () {
                alert('ajax success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('ajax failure');
            }
        });

    }    
}
```

controller code:

```
 public function ajax_delete()
    {

        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->mod->delete_by_id($id); 

    }
```

model code:

```
public function delete_by_id($id)
            {
                $this->db->where('id', $id);
                $this->db->delete('chemicalBottleInfo');
            }
```

what i want to happen is to delete the item from chemicalbottleinfo

Comment: Why are you convinced its not working? Any error codes?

Comment: the output is always "ajax failure".

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your sending your request to the proper url? You're getting a non 200 code back

Comment: Update your error function to show the return, `error: function (xhr, status, error)` and then `console.log(xhr, status, error)` in your error callback.

Comment: please elaborate. if what you mean is opening the proper url into the browser, yeah i did and i put some parameters there earlier, adjust the controller and it work. i'm pretty sure my controller to my model transition is fine.

Comment: Thank you. found the problem. it turns out that i miss something

Comment: data: {'id' : id}, change this line to  data: 'id=' + id,

Comment: @Newbie Care to share the problem / fix? Might help someone in the future.

Comment: are you getting $id in controller plz print and check @newbie

Comment: @saurabhkamble yes yes i get the id in the controller

Comment: @MCMXCII it is just because i forgot to change the name of the controller i use in that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your are passing  id was wrong should not be quotes

```
function Dispose(id){

if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
    {
        // ajax delete data to database
            $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('Login/ajax_delete')?>" , 
            type: 'post',
            data: {id : id},
            success: function () {
                alert('ajax success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('ajax failure');
            }
        });

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

- Adding a check before deleting the id in the table.

  **Javascript:**

> ```
> function Dispose(id){
>             if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
>                 {
>                     // ajax delete data to database
>                         $.ajax({
>                         url:"<?php echo site_url('Login/ajax_delete/'+id)?>" , 
>                         success: function () {
>                             alert('ajax success');
>                         },
>                         error: function () {
>                             alert('ajax failure');
>                         }
>                     });
>                 }  
>         }
> ```

**Controller**:

```
public function ajax_delete($id= '')
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
     if($id != ''){
     $response = $this->usrExist($id, 'chemicalBottleInfo');
    }
   if($response == 1){
     $this->mod->delete_by_id($id); 
   }

}

public function usrchk($id,$tableName) {
        $qry = "SELECT count(*) as cnt from ".tableName." where id= ?";
        $res = $this->db->query($qry,array($id))->result();
        if ($res[0]->cnt > 0) {
           return 1;
        } else {
           return 0;
        }
    }
```